# 3D Menu Attached to an Object?

Tags: unity, gui, menu

So I'm gathering information for my project, and one of the things I want to achieve is to create a very sophisticated crafting system and weapon modification but I want the weapon customization to look in a specific manner.

A very good reference would be Crysis weapon attachments system, where if you open it, your character tilts the weapon and there are few menus popping up, all attached to the weapon, so you can see the menus moving around as your weapon is moving (due to you breathing for example, or walking).

Here is a quick image reference:

[image]

So 1st thing comes to my mind is, how in the name of god should I approach this? Pardon if this is quite easy thing to do, I'm just completely new to Unity. (I have solid C++ background so programming isn't the obstacle)

Edit 1: To be precise, I'm wondering how to work out the positioning of the menus in relation to the weapon. So the menu is moving with the weapon and eventually even turn slightly to give that 3D'ish effect.

Comment: Just attach planes and check fir picking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "attach" 2D menus to a 3D model like this, you can simply define the attachment points somehow in your model data. Often games will already have some kind of system for this, usually representing the attachment point as a 3D point on the model and a normal to indicate "forward" so that physical attachments (like a sniper scope) can be attached.

Unity doesn't appear to have this kind of thing as a first-class feature, but most people seem to implement it via empty named game objects attached to the model in question.

In this case you'd just need the position aspect of such an attachment point. In-game, look up that attachment point's world position and project it onto the screen using, for example, [`Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html). That will give you a position to anchor your menu.

You may want to do something like test if the screen point is closer to the left or right edge of the screen, and use the projected anchor as the left or right origin of the menu (similar for the top and bottom) to prevent the menus from clipping offscreen, or something like that.

Comment: Ahh that sound interesting :D Thank you very very much :)